# How to calculate torque on gearbox?

Tags: gears, torque

I've been trying to figure this out for days and can't seem to get it. I'm trying to create a DIY winch. The motor can pull up to 5500W. It'll be moving things between 45-90 kg (100-200lb) at a steady speed of 1-2m/s.

The motor has a lot of speed, but I need torque, so I've been looking at planetary gearboxes. However, I can't figure out how much Newton-meters of torque the gearbox should rated for.

I'm looking at 10:1 gearboxes. Basically, I want to know how I can calculated what Nm the gearbox will be subjected to so I can get the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest torque applied to the gearbox occurs at the low-speed side. In this case, this is at the load-side of the gearbox, as opposed to the motor-side.

So, all you need to do is compute the torque the load exerts directly to the gearbox. If we know the maximum load to be lifted, and we know the radius of the winch pulley (or more accurately, the horizontal distance between the centre of the gearbox output shaft and the centre of the load), then the torque can be found from the product of the radius and the load in newtons.

Comment: I see, so if the load is 200lb -> 90kg. And the distance between the gearbox/pulley (they're at the same spot for this design) and the load is 5 feet -> 1.5 meters, that would be 135Nm of torque applied?

Comment: It seems like this is was perfect, thanks a lot!